# Error in django poll tutorial

Tags: python, django

I just started with Django, and I'm following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/.

I am recieving error at the shell when I run Question.objects.all () in the shell. I ran dir (Question) as well and it said it did not exist, but I know it does. Remigrated the tables/database since I edited models.py several times and it did not pick up any changes. I also added the unicode method but that did not solve it.Thanks in advance for your help. 
Here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Question

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=8)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Choice
```

Comment: You need to make sure sure that your code matches he tutorial exactly. For instance, you should define `__str__` instead of unicode, use `@python_2_unicode_compatible` if you are using Python 2, and return `self.question_text` and `self.choice_text` instead of `self.Question` and `self.Choice`. If you still get an error, then you need to include the full traceback in your question, otherwise we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

for starters change your `__unicode__` methods

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=8)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha..I know exactly what I did now. I did test it with Question_text and Choice_text before I wrote the question. It works with question_text and choice_text. Problem with typing to actually learn and think about the process as I go is I overlook simple things.
Thanks everyone.